# Is it possible create a copy of only those files that were not committed to SVN?

Tags: file, svn, copy, backup

Sometimes I need to revert many files - near 20 - 50, but need to save the files with local changes - if I in the future will use something.
Project is big - more than 10 000 files.
Is it possible create a copy of only the files that not were committed?
Manually find changes and copy takes near 2 hours - tree of project has many nested folders.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a diff with [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) and then reapplying the diff with [`svn patch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html).

However this is not really how you should work with SVN. Better up if you can create branch with your changes, then you can later merge that branch and share the content with your peers.

Note that creating a branch is relatively cheep in SVN. On the server the files as linked to the original until actually changed. Only your changed files will take space on the server.

**Note:**
`svn diff` only saves the changed lines of your files, not the complete files. But that is enough if you need to reapply the patch.

Comment: +1 for branch. svn patch is also 1.7+ I think - for some reason lots of people are still on 1.6.

Comment: There are other patch tools too. Also TortoiseSVN have had built in patch support for a long time. But you only need to update the client to 1.7 to get access to the patch command.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want copies of files (rather than use svn diff or do a branch), tne approach (a version of which we use for server configuration file backups) is to check which files are modified. The notes below assume you are at the top level of your repo.

For instance, if you run `svn status` you might get output like this:

```
?       plans/software/intro_jan12.log
?       plans/software/intro_jan12.dvi
?       plans/software/data.txt
?       plans/software/intro_jan12.nav
M       plans/software/intro_jan12.pdf
M       plans/software/jan12.tex
?       plans/software/jan12/flowRoot9298.png
?       plans/software/jan12/viewE_comments.pdf
?       plans/software/jan12/team.ps
?       plans/software/jan12/team.png
?       plans/it/plan.log
```

(The ? shown unknown files, the M shows modified files.)

You can then easily extract modified files and do stuff with them by doing something like `svn status | egrep '^M'`.

Turning that into a short shell script that copies modified files elsewhere is pretty easy:

```
# step 1
svn status | egrep '^M' | awk '{ print $2 }' > recipe_file
# step 2
rsync -a --files-from=recipe_file <repo> <dest>
```

Naturally `<dest>` can be on a remote machine.

Presumably, once you have audited the copy files at  you can then do `svn revert -R`.